# Скачивает пустые картинки!

Tags: php, парсер

Устал рабирался скачивает пустые картинки парсер и все тут как не тыкал так понять не смог почему! 
Function:

```
    function _batchDownload(array $urls, &$stats = array()) {
      $mh = curl_multi_init();
      $chs = array();
      $fds = array();
      $now = microtime(true);
      foreach ($urls as $url => $tmp_file) {
        $stats[$url] = array(
          'started'  => $now,
          'finished' => $now,
          'size'     => null,
        );

    $fd = @fopen($tmp_file, 'wb');
    if (!$fd) {
      $result[$url] = null;
      continue;
    }
    $fds[] = $fd;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $chs[] = $ch;
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION  => function($_, $chunk) use($fd) {
        return fwrite($fd, $chunk);
      },
    ));

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
   }

   $result = array();

  $prev_running = $running = null;

  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);

    if ($running != $prev_running) {
      while (true) {
        $info = curl_multi_info_read($mh);
        if (!isset($info['handle']) || (!($ch = $info['handle']))) {
          break;
        }

        $url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $tmp_file = $urls[$url];
        if ($code != 200) {
          if (file_exists($tmp_file)) {
            unlink($tmp_file);
          }
          $tmp_file = null;
        }
        $stats[$url]['finished'] = microtime(true);
        $stats[$url]['size'] = @filesize($tmp_file);

        $result[$url] = $tmp_file;
      }

      $prev_running = $running;
    }

  } while ($running > 0);

  foreach ($chs as $ch) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    curl_close($ch);
  }
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  foreach ($fds as $fd) {
    fclose($fd);
  }

  return $result;
}
```

А вот собственно и исполняющий файл:

```
<?php
    include 'multi.php';
    $x = 'C:\srv\OpenServer\domains\conell-ru\published\publicdata\U0010117NEW\attachments\SC\products_pictures\1';
    $folder = substr($x, 0,-1);
    $file = file('C:\srv\OpenServer\domains\parsers\linkimg.csv');
    $fl = array();
    foreach ($file as $ms) {
        $a = str_replace("\n", '', $ms);
        $b = str_replace('"', "'", $a);
        $fl[] = $b;
    }
    echo count($fl)."\n";
    $param = array();
    foreach ($fl as $dan){
        $jpg = explode(';', $dan);
        $away = $folder.str_replace("/", '', $jpg[1]).'.jpg';
        $param[$jpg[0]]= $away; 
    }
    $urls = array_chunk($param,1);
    foreach ($urls as $key) {
        if(_batchDownload($key) == true){
            echo 'download complete'."\n";
        }
        else{
            echo 'error complete'."\n";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) у вас простая задача - вот и используйте простые решения. Да, curl хорош, но если нужно что-то просто скачать, делайте это через file_get_contents()

2) если у Вас просто массив со ссылками - скормите его (опять же) file_get_contents(). Если не ===false, то сохраняйте. Зачем столько кода?

```
$folder = 'C:\srv\OpenServer\domains\conell-ru\published\publicdata\U0010117NEW\attachments\SC\products_pictures\';
$files = file('C:\srv\OpenServer\domains\parsers\linkimg.csv');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $url_file = file_get_contents(str_replace("\n", '', $file));
    if($url_file) {
        file_put_contents($folder . basename($file));
    } else {
        echo 'файл ' . $file . ' не получен!' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: наверно потому, что мне требуется скачать не 100 картинок а 10000000 и для этого потребуется мульти курд а не curl. 
Убедительная просьба исправить ваш ответ на комментарии т.к. ваш пост не является ответом на мой конкретно поставленный вопрос!

Comment: тем более не всегда хорош file_get_content когда это касается парсинга сайтов!